# How to solve $y'=(2x+y)^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the ODE

$$y'=(2x+y)^2$$

This ODE is Riccati's equation , but I can't bring it to a simpler form.  Thanks

Comment: in general, if $y'=f(ax+by)$, the substitution $ax+by$ is a good place to start

Comment: thank you qbert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $$u=2x+y$$ then you will get $$y'=u'-2$$ can you finish?

Comment: First time I have ever upvoted one of your answers!!!

Comment: Ok, thank you. To understand, in general when I have a Riccati's equation , I saw that I have to make a substitution as y = f + 1/v, right?